# integral and limit, sequence of functions

Tags: real-analysis

Suppose $f$ is continuous and integrable on $(-\infty,\infty)$, and define $f_n(x)=\frac{n}{\pi} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{f(t)}{1+n^2(t-x)^2} dm$
prove that $\lim_{n\to\infty} f_n(x)=f(x)$ pointwise.

I think that we might need to use $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{1}{1+x^2} dx=\pi$, but I don't know how to approach this problem.

Answer (score 0):

If your consider using

$$ u = n(t-x) $$

you will find the integral you mentioned!

PS: Don't forget to change the variable of integration from $\mathrm{d}m$ to $\mathrm{d}t$